# Is Laplacian invariant under reflections?

Tags: real-analysis, laplacian, smooth-functions

It is well known that the Laplacian is invariant under traslations and rotations. I'm trying to prove that the Laplacian is also invariant under reflections across the $y$-axis:
\begin{align*}
\Delta\left(u\left(-x, y\right)\right) = \left(\Delta u\right)\left(-x, y\right)
\end{align*}
whenever $u$ is a smooth function of two variables. Could anyone help to prove this?
Moreover, I would also ask: the Laplacian is also invariant under "all" reflections, i mean, not only under reflections across the $y$-axis?

EDIT (after the answer of @Paul)
Thank you! Could you tell if this is true?
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^{\prime 2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime}}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^{\prime}}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime}}\left( -\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{\prime}} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\left(\Delta u\right)(-x, y) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial (-x)^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\Delta\left(u(-x, y)\right) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^{\prime^2}} +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x'=-x$.  By the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

And just do that again for the second derivative.  Reflections about the $y-$axis work exactly the same.